# c# drawing by mouse

Tags: c#, drawing

I want to draw by mouse by `e.X` and `e.Y`. I know I should use `list<Point>` but I don't know how to do that. Unfortunately I have a problem with `drawlines`, I can't do that.

Somebody told me that I should use `drawlines` and not `Fillellipse`.

Here's the a picture of my current drawing and of the drawing I want to do:

[drawing http://img.fileup.cz/?di=1413056646794](http://img.fileup.cz/?di=1413056646794)

Here's the code:

```
private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

if (action2)
{
stetec = new SolidBrush(lbl_color.BackColor);
Graphics kp = panel1.CreateGraphics();
kp.FillEllipse(stetec, e.X, e.Y, 14, 14);
kp.Dispose();
}
}

private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
action2 = false;


}

private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
action2 = true;
}

private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{


}
```

Answer (score 16):

So, first off, don't perform your drawing directly inside of the MouseMove handler.  Keep all of your drawing code in your OnPaint override and use the supplied graphics object there. Simply maintain a collection of points from within the MouseMove handler.  The reason for this (well, one reason) is that OnPaint will be called unpredictably and your drawing will be wiped out because the logic will not be executed within OnPaint.  Try minimizing your window and maximizing it again to see what I mean.

As for your other problem, like I said, simply maintain a collection of `Point` objects.  Override OnPaint and draw the points there using the [Graphcis.DrawLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ewkcdb3.aspx) method which accepts a collection of points.  So your code becomes something like...

```
private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{    
  if (action2)
  {
    myPointList.Add( e.Location );
    panel1.Invalidate(); //force a repaint
  }
}

private void panel1_Paint( object sender, PaintEventArgs e )
{
    e.Graphics.DrawLines( Pens.Black, myPointList );
}
```

I would also suggest subclassing Panel (or whichever control you use) and placing the drawing logic there.  In that case simply override the `OnPaint` method instead of handling the `Paint` event.

EDIT: I thought that I should also comment on why your code doesn't work.  You will not receive a MouseMove event for every single pixel that the mouse traverses.  The OS simply does not give you that level of resolution.  Instead you will get the event at intervals.  You can see this manifest in the gaps between your ellipses.  You need to connect a line between each point, which is what the `DrawLines` method will do for you. You can see the same effect if you draw a line very rapidly in MSPaint.  The line will not have nice counters that follow exactly where the mouse was, but instead the line will be very jagged.

Comment: To make this work, declare myPointList as a list<T> and then go: e.Graphics.DrawLines(Pens.Black, myPointList.ToArray());

Answer (score 5):

```
namespace Drawing
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        bool draw = false;

        int pX = -1;
        int pY = -1;

        Bitmap drawing;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            drawing = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height, panel1.CreateGraphics());
            Graphics.FromImage(drawing).Clear(Color.White);
        }

        private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (draw)
            {
                Graphics panel = Graphics.FromImage(drawing);

                Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 14);

                pen.EndCap = LineCap.Round;
                pen.StartCap = LineCap.Round;

                panel.DrawLine(pen, pX, pY, e.X, e.Y);

                panel1.CreateGraphics().DrawImageUnscaled(drawing, new Point(0, 0));
            }

            pX = e.X;
            pY = e.Y;
        }

        private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            draw = true;

            pX = e.X;
            pY = e.Y;
        }

        private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            draw = false;
        }

        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(drawing, new Point(0, 0));
        }
    }
}
```

Also posted on my blog - http://techtt.hassantt.com/2011/05/c-draw-on-panel.html

Comment: Probably a good idea to post it here as well in case that page disappears at some point.

Comment: @Hassan Voyeau a good idea would be to make use of the using statement in your code :)